# Error compiling class from commandline

Tags: java, servlets, compilation

I try to compile Select.java servlet from Mac terminal with the following command;

```
MyComputer-iMac:src name$ javac -Xlint:unchecked  
-classpath /Users/name/Development/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/lib
/servlet-api.jar:classes:.com/web/Select.java
```

and I get this error;

```
com/web/Select.java:18: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class List
location: class com.web.Select
List result=be.getBrands(color);
^
```

I have imported  java.io in my Select class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Who said list was java.io? Lists are usually java.util.List

Comment: @Adel Boutros Lol I must be drunk, tnx I will accept after 10 minutes